# WAP vs XHTML-MP

Tags: asp.net, wap, xhtml-mp

Last year we develop intranet web site using WAP and ASP.NET for server side, the site was already on production and was considered successful. We use low end handset which had built in Openwave version 6.

Now we update the application using XHTML-MP, because we think this will be the future mobile application technology that will be supported. But the performance was very worse. We tested both application on same time and same module, the new application is 10 seconds (average) longer than the old one. We eliminate several possibility such as redirect and we already compress the page (both application pare are 2 kb size). During the test, we encountered the XHTML-MP application often get network error, such "Cannot resolve host name" and "Request Time Out", but not on the WAP application using the same device and browser. The application use the same proxy. We tested both using the direct access and using proxy (WAP Gateway).

We put logger in our application that track how long application was executed in server time, and it was less than a seconds.

We already invest so much time and money on this, but we can't figure out what is the cause of problem.

Does this mean that rendering XHTML-MP was longer than rendering WAP on Openwave browser? And why I haven't see any documents on Internet that mention about this? Is developing new web mobile using XHTML-MP are suggested?

Any help and suggestion are very appreciate.

ucin

Answer (score 0):

May I ask how much css formatting are you doing?  It's recommended that you don't use css extensively to format the page since many handsets don't have enough power to process that (at least a few years ago, that was the case).

Comment: Hi Jack, we use little css and embedded with every page, since using url is not working in openwave 6.1, thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously very device (or device range) specific,  could you tell us which devices struggle to format xhtml?

If so, is it not possible to show WML to these old troublesome devices?  You could look at their agent string for example to detect what markup to output them.